# R to Hive connection using RHive Package

Tags: r, hive

I installed R 2.15.2 on Windows PC.
Hadoop & Hive are on another PC.
I loaded RHive and its dependencies in to R.
Now i am trying to connect to Hive.

```
> Sys.setenv(HIVE_HOME="/home/hadoop/hive-0.7.0-cdh3u0")
> Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u0")
> library(RHive)
> rhive.env(ALL=TRUE)
```

> Hive Home Directory : /home/hadoop/hive-0.7.0-cdh3u0
>   Hadoop Home Directory : /home/hadoop/hive-0.7.0-cdh3u0
>   Hadoop Conf Directory :
>   No RServe
>   Disconnected HiveServer and HDFS
>   RHive Library List
>   C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/library/RHive/java/rhive_udf.jar /home/hadoop/hive-0.7.0-cdh3u0/conf

```
> rhive.init()
```

> [1] "there is no slaves file of HADOOP. so you should pass hosts argument when you call rhive.connect()."
>   Error in .jnew("org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration") : 
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "rt") :
>     cannot open file '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u0/conf/slaves': No such file or directory

```
> rhive.connect(hdfsurl="hdfs://212.63.135.149:9000/")
```

> Error in .jnew("org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration") : 
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

The result is error in connection!

even tried 
`rhive.connect(host = "212.63.135.149", port = 10000, hdfsurl="hdfs://212.63.135.149:9000/")` , but no use.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago when installing RHive. It is because some jar files are not in the classpath which is set in rhive.init.
You need to set the arguments hive, libs, hadoop_home, hadoop_conf, hlibs which indicate where these jar files are located.

I first installed from source, that worked with rhive.init but rhive.connect did not work properly. It did work like a charm when I installed Hive through the Cloudera manager https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/Hive+Installation. So I advise you to follow the instructions there, it is well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, it is because wrong Hadoop version you use.

RHive does not work with YARN, then use hadoop-0.20.205.0 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with fixing rhive_udf.jar classpath (found in RHive source directory, after build)

```
mkdir –p /usr/lib64/R/library/RHive/java
cp rhive_udf.jar //usr/lib64/R/library/RHive/java
chmod 755 /usr/lib64/R/library/RHive/java/rhive_udf.jar
R
> library("rJava")
> .jinit()
> .jaddClassPath("/usr/lib64/R/library/RHive/java/rhive_udf.jar")
```

Then test newly added classpath with :

```
> .jclassPath()
```

You should see '/usr/lib64/R/library/RHive/java/rhive_udf.jar' in a list!

Then restart R - and here you go!